# unable to use lapply with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, summarization

I am trying to create a summary of all character variables in a data.table. Basically to get total observation count, missing values, category with highest frequency etc. However I am not able correctly use `lapply` for the same. Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(data.table)

#Function to analyze one variable at a time
analyze_char_var <- function(x) {
  y = names(x)
  z = x[,.N,by=y]
  w = setorder(z,-N)

  out = data.table( 
    total_obs = nrow(x),
    missing_obs = sum(is.na(x)),
    unique_cats = nrow(z),
    top_cat = z[1,1],
    top_freq = z[1,2]
  )
  return(out)
}
#Function to analyze all variables. I want to use lapply instead of loop
analyze_all_char <- function(dt) {
  dt.char = dt[,sapply(dt,class)=="character", with=FALSE]
  mylist = vector('list', length(dt.char))
  for (i in 1:length(dt.char)){
    x = dt.char[,i,with=FALSE]
    mylist[[i]] = analyze_char_var(x)
  }
  return(mylist)
}

dt = data.table(
  var1 = c('a', 'a', 'b','b', 'c'),
  var2 = 1:5,
  var3 = c('low','low','high','med',NA)
)
dt.analysis = analyze_all_char(dt)
```

Just using `dt.analysis = dt.char[,lapply(.SD,analyze_char_var)]` produces an error `Error in x[, .N, by = y] : incorrect number of dimensions`. I tried some variations, but could not get it to work.

**EDIT:** Finally this works for me. However, looks very clumsy. Reconverting the input vector into data.table and then using `lapply` in a data.frame manner.

```
test_func <- function(x) {
  dt = as.data.table(x)
  dt.summ = dt[,.N,by='x'] #by default name is x
  # I was stuck in the above line, I was trying all 
  # sort of bad tricks to get the name of grouping variable 


  dt.summ.sorted = setorder(dt.summ,-N)
  out = data.table(
    total_obs = nrow(dt),
    missing_obs = sum(is.na(dt)),
    unique_cats = nrow(dt.summ.sorted),
    top_cat = dt.summ.sorted[1,1],
    top_freq = dt.summ.sorted[1,2]
  )
  return(out)
}

dt.char = dt[,sapply(dt,class)=="character", with=FALSE]
lapply(dt.char,test_func)
```

Comment: If you analyze one variable at a time, in `analyze_char_var` x will be a vector and not a data.table. You need to reconsider the whole design of the functions.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that and was trying to "convert" the vector back into data table, but somehow was making some mistake which I was not able to catch since 2 hours. Finally got it to work, but it doesn't look elegant at all. Putting it as edit in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to create a summary of all character variables in a data.table. Basically to get total observation count, missing values, category with highest frequency etc.

Since all the cols of interest have the same type, you can use `melt` to go to long form:

```
melt(dt.char <- Filter(is.character, dt), meas=names(dt.char))[, {

  tabula = setDT(list(value))[, .N, by="V1"][order(-N, V1)]

  .(
    NOBS  = .N,
    NNA   = sum(is.na(value)),
    NVALS = nrow(tabula),
    HIVAL = tabula$V1[1L],
    NHI   = tabula$N[1L]
  )
}, by=variable]

#    variable NOBS NNA NVALS HIVAL NHI
# 1:     var1    5   0     3     a   2
# 2:     var3    5   1     4   low   2
```

To exclude NA as a category (showing up in NVALS and possibly HIVAL, NHI), change `[, .N, by="V1"]` to `[!is.na(V1), .N, by="V1"]` above.

I doubt that performance is important for this task, but this should be reasonably efficient.

Comment: This will definitly be more efficient than for-loop and apply, although I am getting different results for 'NVALS'. Your code gives 3 & 3, while the other ones give 3 & 4.

Comment: @SeGa Ah, good catch. Reading the OP's description, I figured they wouldn't count NA as a valid category, but they do... will edit now. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't count NA as valid category, but that was unimportant at that moment., Thank for great solution as always.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
analyze_all_char <- function(dt) {
  dt.char = dt[,sapply(dt,class)=="character", with=FALSE]
  mylist = lapply(1:length(dt.char), function(i) {
    x = dt.char[,i,with=FALSE]
    analyze_char_var(x)
  })
  return(mylist)
}
```

---

**Benchmarking** it, you wont see too much performance gain. If you're after performance, I would suggest doing the calculation with `data.table` operations.

I increased the data.frame and checked the for-loop, lapply and @Frank's solution. The clear winner is `data.table`!

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
>  forloop 4.070700 4.685024 7.220436 6.709425 8.564480 35.81166   500   b
>   lapply 3.988765 4.750347 7.367764 6.815147 8.613754 56.58692   500   b
>  lapply1 4.008022 4.728257 7.390874 6.786074 8.551453 51.31551   500   b
>      dtf 2.984400 3.320825 5.451909 4.699372 6.661660 40.85501   500  a
> ```

Full Code:

```
dt = data.table(
  var1 = rep(c('a', 'a', 'b','b', 'c'),100),
  var2 = rep(1:5,100),
  var3 = rep(c('low','low','high','med',NA),100)
)

analyze_all_char <- function(dt) {
  dt.char = dt[,sapply(dt,class)=="character", with=FALSE]
  mylist = list()
  for (i in 1:length(dt.char)){
    x = dt.char[,i,with=FALSE]
    mylist[[i]] = analyze_char_var(x)
  }
  return(mylist)
}
analyze_all_char_l <- function(dt) {
  dt.char = dt[,sapply(dt,class)=="character", with=FALSE]
  mylist = lapply(1:length(dt.char), function(i) {
    x = dt.char[,i,with=FALSE]
    analyze_char_var(x)
  })
  return(mylist)
}
analyze_all_char_l1 <- function(dt) {
  dt.char = dt[,sapply(dt,class)=="character", with=FALSE]
  mylist = lapply(1:length(dt.char), function(i) {
    analyze_char_var(dt.char[,i,with=FALSE])
  })
  return(mylist)
}
dtf <- function() {
  melt(dt.char <- Filter(is.character, dt), meas=names(dt.char))[, {
    tabula = setDT(list(value))[, .N, by="V1"][order(-N, V1)]
    .(
      NOBS  = .N,
      NNA   = sum(is.na(value)),
      NVALS = nrow(tabula),
      HIVAL = tabula$V1[1L],
      NHI   = tabula$N[1L]
    )
  }, by=variable]
}

analyze_all_char(dt)
analyze_all_char_l(dt)
analyze_all_char_l1(dt)
dtf()

library(microbenchmark)
mc <- microbenchmark(times=500,
  forloop = analyze_all_char(dt),
  lapply = analyze_all_char_l(dt),
  lapply1 = analyze_all_char_l1(dt),
  dtf = dtf()
)
mc
```

Comment: it works, but looks very similar to my for loop, I wonder if it actually improve performance.

Comment: I just included some benchmarks. You wont see any performance improvements with `lapply`. Actually the lapply might also be slower sometimes..

Comment: thanks for performance analysis. There is a typo in the `mc` block. It should be `analyze_all_char_l` and not `analyze_all_char_1`

Comment: Thank you, actually there were 2 typos ;)